# How do I bind multiple buttons to one action in Portal Companion Collection?

Tags: portal-companion-collection

The default controls for Portal Companion Collection on Switch have two buttons bound to Pickup/Use, either <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>. I want to change the Pickup/Use controls so I can use either <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>. However, when I modify the button I'm only able to specify one button at a time, and any other buttons on the action are cleared.

How can I set both <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> as Pickup/Use buttons in Portal Companion Collection?

[image: Controller options]